# Azure function app traces exhibiting strange behavior

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app, appinsights

I have 10+ azure function apps deployed. Out of them only one function app always writes a trace message "Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 200" every 10 seconds. I can not find the source from where this log is coming. My host.json looks like below

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": { "routePrefix": "api" }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it a httptrigger function, right? Even if you didn't run the function, is the trace message still sent?

Comment: Yes the trace message still appears even if I am not triggering the function. Btw I am not writing this log message anywhere in my function app.

Comment: The trace message is auto-generated by the function host(not a function instance like a httptrigger function). Can you create another httptrigger function and see if the trace there?

Comment: I have around 13 function apps deployed. And all of them have many http triggered functions. But out of them only one function app is writing these traces. And that is where I am confused.

Comment: Another possible reason is that the message indicates the health check is in progress. But not sure why it only occurs for this one.

Comment: @DevMJ I have the same issue, did you found which route was causing this?

Answer (score 1):

When you have some unwanted logs in application insights, click on it and see what's the category:

[image: Trace]

As you can see, the category is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult` and the severity level is `Information`.

What I did was to ignore all the logs with lower level than `Warning` from all the categories starting with `Microsoft`. I configured it in the `host.json` file:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Controllers.Host": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I also set `Warning` value to `Host.Controllers.Host` to avoid messages like `Ping Status: { "hostState": "Running" }`

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is that the message indicates the health check is in progress. But I'm not sure in which condition it will do the check.

This should not impact the function. And if you want to find out the root cause, it's better to raise a support ticket, the support team may check the backend for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Are any of your functions marked with the [Disabled] attribute, or disabled in the portal? I have a feeling that the framework performs some kind of health check on them. After I removed the [Disabled] functions from my code, the health check messaging stopped.

Comment: If it's an another question, please don't add it as an answer. You can comment.